# Onhover of Navigation change to light color background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing a functionality for my website, where I want a functionality as same [here](http://www.marksandspencer.com/).

In detail: When I hover on navigation, I want to make the background light.

Do let me know if needed anything else.

Comment: use css or jquery, on hover, set opacity for div or image

Comment: Need the code you have tried to make this work...Markup HTML and CSS

Comment: @Piyush: Hi piyush, I want that for the whole `<body>` tag, how to use that ?

Comment: @Priyanka:-Then set opacity for <body> tag

Comment: @Piyush: I already tried that, but it is not working, do let me know if you need html for that.

Comment: @Priyanks:- Include your relevant code in question

Comment: see this link as : http://jsfiddle.net/ex3vy5jj/

Comment: My answers works perfectly on jsfiddle. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/y9nzz/118/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question. See the example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul li").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).addClass('light-bg', 1000);
       $('body').addClass('new-body-bg', 1000);
      
       });
   
      $("ul li").mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('light-bg', 1000);
        $('body').removeClass('new-body-bg', 1000);

      }); });
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: #ddd; /* Choose the color of your choice */
  height: 40px;
  }


li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 15px;
  }

.light-bg {
  background-color: #fff; /* Choose the color of your choice */
 line-height: 20px;
  }

 .new-body-bg {
  background-color: #ccc; /* Choose the color of your choice */
  position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#"> One </a></li>
 <li><a href="#"> Two </a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Three </a></li>
 <li><a href="#"> Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

[It works perfectly on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9nzz/118/)

Comment: I need it for the whole body, not for the navigation background

Comment: Trying adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> to the header of your website and also be sure that you didn't sop the script from loading.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/tekokmke/1/

Without using jQuery,

1. you want to find all of the elements you want to do this to
2. then you want to loop through them
3. You'll apply two listeners to each one, one for entering and one for leaving.

js:

```
var mes = document.querySelectorAll(".me");

function changeIn(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
}

function changeOut(){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkgray";
}

for(i = 0; i < mes.length; i++){
       mes[i].onmouseenter = changeIn;
       mes[i].onmouseleave = changeOut;
}
```

Comment: but it will work only for that selective class. I need to change the body color on hover navigation menu

Comment: The other answer by @sleek-geek is better code, but I wanted to still explain why so you'd learn a little more about how it works and keep the answer a little simpler.